# My :hover in CSS will only affect a pice of my div/image

Tags: html, css, image, hover, responsive

So, I'm stuck.. I've been trying to figure out what is going wrong with my code. I am trying to get my image to darken a bit when i hover over it. I do this in CSS. It works BUT it only cover half of my image. When my text is added it will only show hover function below my text, and when i remove the text, it will only show 1/3 of the image, from the top.

I am a noob, and hopefully this is a easy fix for someone out there!

My html:

```html
<div class="contentbild1">
    <picture><source media="(min-width: 736px)" srcset="Biler/bildtest.jpg" style="width:100%;"><img src="Biler/bildtestmobil.jpg" alt="Trädvård" style="width:100%;"></picture>
    <div class="contentbildtext1">
    <font class="Contenttext">TRÄDVÅRD</font>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```css
.contentbild1{
  position: relative;
}
.contentbild1:hover > div {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.contentbildtext1{    
  position: absolute;
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:5.8%;  
  text-align:center;
    font-family:Palatino,Palatino Linotype,Palatino LT STD,Book Antiqua,Georgia,serif;
    color:orange;
    font-size:200%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 736px){
    .contentbildtext1{
     padding-top:17%;  
    }
}
```

To be fair, I dont know alot, mostly I goolge what I want and find code or functions that I need. This problem is beyond me. Maybe it's cus my code is a mess(?).

I also had a hard time positioning my text in the center, maybe thats visible in the code, it works OK now anyway.

Thankful for some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check add 'bottom: 0;' to .contentbildtext1 css class.

```
  .contentbildtext1{    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5.8%;  
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Palatino,Palatino Linotype,Palatino LT STD,Book Antiqua,Georgia,serif;
    color: orange;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `.contentbild1` black not only the `.contentbild1 > div`:

```css
.contentbild1{
  position: relative;
}
.contentbild1:hover {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.contentbildtext1{    
  position: absolute;
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:5.8%;  
  text-align:center;
    font-family:Palatino,Palatino Linotype,Palatino LT STD,Book Antiqua,Georgia,serif;
    color:orange;
    font-size:200%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px){
    .contentbildtext1{
     padding-top:17%;  
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="contentbild1">
    <picture><source media="(min-width: 736px)" srcset="Biler/bildtest.jpg" style="width:100%;"><img src="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Trädvård" style="width:100%;"></picture>
    <div class="contentbildtext1">
    <font class="Contenttext">TRÄDVÅRD</font>
    </div>
</div>
```